# Excel VBA Macro select multiple ranges, even duplicate, and export to pdf

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

So, I managed to export specific range on my only sheet to PDF, no problems here.

Now I would like to create PDF from multiple ranges on different pages.

For example:

- 1st page of PDF has first 5 columns of active sheet and columns from 6-10. So, range A1:E10 && F1:J10
- 2nd page of PDF has first 5 columns of active sheet and columns 10-15. So, range from A1:E10 && K1:O10
- 3rd page has range from A1:E10 && P1:T10

And so on..

Snippet

```
Private Sub cmdPrintJul_Click()
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

  Set ws1 = Worksheets("YTD")
  ws1.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:K48"
  Set ws2 = Worksheets("July")
  ws2.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:G45"

  Worksheets(Array(ws1.Name, ws2.Name)).Select
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="e:\saved\July2016.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

  ws1.Activate
  Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Does that accross multiple sheets, I need it on a single sheet, but concatenate multiple ranges together.
Setting pages is probably gonna be done via PageSize, selecting the one that page breaks each combined range to its own page.

I tried with:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Celo leto 2019")
ws1.PageSetup.printArea = "B2:K39"
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Celo leto 2019")
ws2.PageSetup.printArea = "AQ2:BS39"

Worksheets(Array(ws1.Name, ws2.Name)).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
  Filename:=strPathFile, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=True

ws1.Activate
Range("A1").Select
```

But it only exports ws2 range..

Comment: I don't think exporting to PDF in Excel supports what you propose. Are you able to do it in the UI, as a user?

Comment: I did manage to do it partially, had to copy each data range to new sheet and concatenate there, then export to pdf range from different sheets with snippet above..

Comment: Yes, you'd need that kind of approach.